# UTF8 from PHP to JS Alert

Tags: javascript, php

I'm passing a string to a VAR and then that var into an onclick event. The problem is that the string wont come out with UTF8. I have tried already the utf8_encode and decode and nothing. i have the Meta in my head `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and still nothing. Any tips how to make it UTF8? thanks. [image]

```
(this is in my controller)$msg = 'Tem a certeza que deseja remover o inventário?';

(in my view).....rio"] . '" onclick="return confirm_box(\'' . $msg . '\')"  class="btn btn-p......
```

Comment: What do the HTTP headers in the actual response look like?

Comment: After i click, the message that goes into the function is already all messed up. I made a break point on chrome and already saw that the message was all messed up when it reaches the JS function.

Comment: Well at some point the content gets from your server to the browser. That's the HTTP transaction I'm talking about. If the server is not using the correct character set in the `Content-Type` header, it could cause that problem.

Comment: The ``content-type`` header comes out as ````application/javascript````